# Function to find cosine similarity between rows using non null common columns only

Tags: python, pandas, function, trigonometry

I want to write a function to find the cosine similarity between an index row (query) and every other row in the dataframe, by using the common columns only. The problem I face is that the common non null columns may differ between rows. I have tried replacing the values with 0's, as advised when I asked a similar question before, but this is not the output or method I am looking for so I am trying to be more specific here. For example my query is like so:

```
     A    B   C   D    E   F
1    3   Nan  2   1   Nan  4
```

and this is contained in the similar_rows data frame:

```
     A    B   C   D    E   F
0    2    3  Nan  3    1  Nan
1    3   Nan  2   1   Nan  4
2    Nan  4   1   3   Nan  5
```

Therefore the cosine similarity should be found between the query (which in this case is index 1) and both 0 and 2 separately using only their non null common columns. So the cosine similarity between 0 and 1 should be found using only columns A and D as they are both non null.

My function so far looks like this:

```
def sims(index):
    #find_similar_times finds all times within a minutes threshold of the index row, not necessary to know that for this question but just giving some context
    similar_rows = find_similar_rows(index)
    #finding the columns of the query
    query_cols = similar_rows.loc[index]
    #getting them columns as a list after finding only non null columns of the query
    q_cols_names = query_cols[query_cols.notnull()]
    q_cols_names = list(q_cols_names.index)
    #putting the query into it's own dataframe
    qs = pd.DataFrame(query_cols[q_cols_names])
    qs = qs.T

    #this is where the error occurs. I am not sure why
    result = similar_rows[q_cols_names].apply(lambda row: cosine(row, qs))

    return result
    #the error says ('shapes (33,) and (24,) not aligned: 33 (dim 0) != 24 (dim 0)', (obviously my actual dataframe is different from above). I am not sure what this error is telling me
```

This is a complicated problem to explain so apologies in advance if it is not clear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
    matrix = pd.DataFrame({"A": a, "B": b})
    matrix = matrix.dropna(axis = 0, how='any')
    a = matrix[['A']]
    b = matrix[['B']]
    return 1 - (cosine(a, b))

def sims(index):
    #find_similar_times finds all times within a minutes threshold of the index row, not necessary to know that for this question but just giving some context
    similar_rows = find_similar_rows(index)
    similar_rows = similar_rows.filter(like='to')
    #finding the columns of the query
    query_cols = list(similar_rows.loc[index])
    similar_rows = similar_rows.drop([index], axis = 0)
    #getting them columns as a list after finding only non null columns of the query
    result = similar_rows.apply(lambda row: cosine_similarity(list(row), query_cols), axis = 1)
    result = result.sort_values(ascending = False) #finding the most similar
    result = result.head(10)


    return result
```